# Obtaining values from dictionary in OOP: "AttributeError"

Tags: python, oop, dictionary

I am trying to get values from my dictionary VALUES. My program creates combination of possible positions and gets the last position. Then I want to get the value. Everything works well here except indicated .get_value method. When I execute this code I receive:

AttributeError: 'Combination' object has no attribute 'get_value'

Theoretically it should be easy but I am new to OOP and I don't see what is wrong here.

```
X = ['A','B','C']  
Y = ['1','2','3']

VALUES = {'A':10, 'B': 50, 'C':-20}

class Combination:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        if (x in X) and (y in Y):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y
        else:
            print "WRONG!!"

    def __repr__ (self):
        return self.x+self.y

    def get_x(self):
        return self.x

    def get_y(self):
        return self.y

class Position:
    def __init__(self):
        self.xy = []
        for i in X:
            for j in Y:
                self.xy.append(Combination(i,j))

    def choose_last(self):
        return self.xy.pop()

    def __str__(self):
        return "List contains: " + str(self.xy)

class Operation1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.operation1 = []

    def __str__(self):
        s = str(self.operation1)
        return s

    def get_value(self):
        V = VALUES.get(self)
        return V

pos = Position()
print pos
last_item = pos.choose_last()
print "Last item:", last_item, pos

last_value = last_item.get_value() # <---- Here is a problem
```

How can I obtain value of my position? Value is determined by the X value - this is A,B or C. In the dictionary I have a numeral value for the letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are appending objects of `Combination` into `xy` of `Position`. When you say `choose_last`, it will return the last `Combination` object inserted into `xy`. And you are trying to invoke `get_value` method on a `Combination` object, which doesnt have that method. Thats why you are getting that error.
2. Always use new style classes.

Comment: Can I somehow use my Operation1 class to get this value? Because later I would like to use this class more?